# Limit amount of results returned

Tags: post, limit, attachment

How can I limit the amount of results returned?

```
$images = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
    AND ID in ($meta)
    ORDER BY menu_order ASC
");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit to 5 rows, use the following query:

```
$images = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
    AND ID in ($meta)
    ORDER BY menu_order ASC
    LIMIT 5
");
```

Comment: Yes SQL is a pain like that. Can take some getting used to.